# Server Error after trying to update the functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, error, theme, http-code-500

I recently tried to change the logo on Genesis themed WordPress site using this tutorial:

```
http://anewtab.com/add-logo-genesis-theme
```

I added

```
add_theme_support( 'genesis-custom-header', array( 'width' => 960, 'h
```

To Dashboard->Editor->functions.php as said in the tutorial, and updated the theme. 
It didn't really work as I hoped so I deleted the same line and updated it, now I get the server error as below and can't access to my site.

I get this message when I try to access to my site.

```
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.vivatveritas.com/wp-admin/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial isn't displaying the code correctly, it should be:

```
add_theme_support( 'genesis-custom-header', array( 'width' =&gt; 960, 'height' =&gt; 100 ) );
```

So add this piece to your existing line and you should be good.

```
eight' =&gt; 100 ) );
```

Comment: toomanyairmiles, Thank you for your response. Now I can't access to any of my pages on the site at all. I can't even go to my Dashboard . Any advise?

Comment: @Chie you'll need to connect to your server via FTP and go to wp-content > themes > genesis and download the functions.php file. Amend the line and upload it again.

Comment: toomanyairmiles, thank you! i must have deleted something while i try to modify the functions.php file.

Comment: @Chie the line of code you added was incomplete, without the ); on the end of the line wordpress cannot understand the rest of the functions file, if you add the extra bit on the end it will fix the problem and let you back into wordpress